# Julia multidimensional array

Tags: arrays, dataframe, multidimensional-array, julia

I have multidimensional array stored in dataframe in `Julia`.

```
dfy = DataFrame(a = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]], b = ["M","F","F"])
3×2 DataFrame
│ Row │ a         │ b      │
│     │ Array…    │ String │
├─────┼───────────┼────────┤
│ 1   │ [1, 2, 3] │ M      │
│ 2   │ [4, 5, 6] │ F      │
│ 3   │ [7, 8, 9] │ F      │
```

I would like to get the first column "a" and store the first value in each element in X1 (1,4,7) and second value in each row in X2 (2,5,8) and third value in each row in X3 (3,6,9).

How can we accomplish this in `Julia` programming language?

Comment: Just a sidenote: That's not a multidimensional array, but a vector of vectors. Unlike e.g. numpy, Julia distinguishes between those two cases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I give several options to show you what you can do.

Before I give my options let me comment on the alternative answer, which in general is a most natural way to get what you want, if you want to update the existing data frame. DataFrames.jl does not support indexing by a column name only. DataFrame.jl is a two dimensional object and thus it requires passing both row and column index like this:

```
julia> for i in 1:3
           dfy[:, "X$i"] = getindex.(dfy.a, i)
       end

julia> dfy
3×5 DataFrame
│ Row │ a         │ b      │ X1    │ X2    │ X3    │
│     │ Array…    │ String │ Int64 │ Int64 │ Int64 │
├─────┼───────────┼────────┼───────┼───────┼───────┤
│ 1   │ [1, 2, 3] │ M      │ 1     │ 2     │ 3     │
│ 2   │ [4, 5, 6] │ F      │ 4     │ 5     │ 6     │
│ 3   │ [7, 8, 9] │ F      │ 7     │ 8     │ 9     │
```

(note that this is what the error message prompts you to do -- i.e. that `setindex!` requires one more argument to be passed)

Now some more advanced options. The first is:

```
julia> rename!(x -> "X"*x, DataFrame(Tuple.(dfy.a)))
3×3 DataFrame
│ Row │ X1    │ X2    │ X3    │
│     │ Int64 │ Int64 │ Int64 │
├─────┼───────┼───────┼───────┤
│ 1   │ 1     │ 2     │ 3     │
│ 2   │ 4     │ 5     │ 6     │
│ 3   │ 7     │ 8     │ 9     │
```

because I understand you want a new data frame,
or to create a new data frame combining old an new columns just use horizontal concatentation:

```
julia> [dfy rename!(x -> "X"*x, DataFrame(Tuple.(dfy.a)))]
3×5 DataFrame
│ Row │ a         │ b      │ X1    │ X2    │ X3    │
│     │ Array…    │ String │ Int64 │ Int64 │ Int64 │
├─────┼───────────┼────────┼───────┼───────┼───────┤
│ 1   │ [1, 2, 3] │ M      │ 1     │ 2     │ 3     │
│ 2   │ [4, 5, 6] │ F      │ 4     │ 5     │ 6     │
│ 3   │ [7, 8, 9] │ F      │ 7     │ 8     │ 9     │
```

Finally, if you want to update the existing data frame you can write:

```
julia> transform!(dfy, [:a => (x -> getindex.(x, i)) => "X$i" for i in 1:3]...)
3×5 DataFrame
│ Row │ a         │ b      │ X1    │ X2    │ X3    │
│     │ Array…    │ String │ Int64 │ Int64 │ Int64 │
├─────┼───────────┼────────┼───────┼───────┼───────┤
│ 1   │ [1, 2, 3] │ M      │ 1     │ 2     │ 3     │
│ 2   │ [4, 5, 6] │ F      │ 4     │ 5     │ 6     │
│ 3   │ [7, 8, 9] │ F      │ 7     │ 8     │ 9     │
```

Comment: for some strange reason I still get the error, when I execute the following code: `MethodError: no method matching setindex!(::DataFrame, ::Array{Float64,1}, ::String)
Closest candidates are:
  setindex!(::DataFrame, ::Any, ::Any, !Matched::Colon) at C:\.julia\packages\DataFrames\S3ZFo\src\deprecated.jl:1516
  setindex!(::DataFrame, ::AbstractArray{T,1} where T, !Matched::typeof(!), !Matched::Union{Signed, Symbol, Unsigned})
  setindex!(::DataFrame, ::AbstractArray{T,1} where T, !Matched::Union{Signed, Symbol, Unsigned}) at deprecated.jl:65`

Comment: can you please paste what code you try to execute as from the error message I do not see the code in this message that would lead to this error message.

Comment: I found the issue: `"X$i"` does not work in `DataFrames v0.20.2` only `Symbol(:X, i)` works.

Comment: Please consider upgrading. There are many bug fixes in 0.21 in comparison to 0.20

Comment: Thank you. How to get latest version? when I `add DataFrames`  I only get 0.20. Thanks. I have Julia `v.1.4.2`

Comment: Julia version is unrelated. Do `add DataFrames@0.21 and see what error you get - this will show you what conflicting package you have.

Comment: No Error, The update went smoothly, I have the latest version, thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2):

You could try this:

```
for i in 1:3
    dfy[:, "X$i"] = getindex.(dfy.a,i)
end
```

Once run here is the result:

```
julia> dfy
3×5 DataFrame
│ Row │ a         │ b      │ X1    │ X2    │ X3    │
│     │ Array…    │ String │ Int64 │ Int64 │ Int64 │
├─────┼───────────┼────────┼───────┼───────┼───────┤
│ 1   │ [1, 2, 3] │ M      │ 1     │ 2     │ 3     │
│ 2   │ [4, 5, 6] │ F      │ 4     │ 5     │ 6     │
│ 3   │ [7, 8, 9] │ F      │ 7     │ 8     │ 9     │
```

The dot `.` after `getindex` is a vectorization operator and hence you are gettinh `i`-th element from each row of the `a` column of your `DataFrame`.

Comment: Thank you, Im getting following error message when I run the code. `MethodError: no method matching setindex!(::DataFrame, ::Array{Int64,1}, ::String)
Closest candidates are:
  setindex!(::DataFrame, ::Any, ::Any, !Matched::Colon)`

Comment: I used depreciated syntax (now I updated the code). The problem is that now Julia by default is not showing depreciation warnings and I started my Julia just by `julia` instead of `julia --depwarn=yes`. On the other hand most likely your configuration was `julia --depwarn=error` and you saw an error instead of a warning.